# I want to keep only the lines before a certain string in a txt file

Tags: python, regex, string, partition, txt

I want all lines before the line that has string 'VarList'. I cannot understand why the solutions proposed elsewhere do not work for my txt file.

To simplify:

I have many .txt files that look like this:

```
    text1=text
    text2=text
    (...)
    textN=text
    VarList=text
    (...)
    End
```

I just want this:

```
    text1=text
    text2=text
    (...)
    textN=text
```

How can I get it for all txt files in a directory path?

First I have tried this:

```
import os

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\nigel\\OneDrive\\Documents\\LAB\\lean\\.txt'):
    for file in files:
        output=[]
        with open(file, 'r') as inF:
            for line in inF:
                output.append(line)
                if 'VarList' in line: break
        f=open(file, 'w')
        blank=['']
        [f.write(x) for x in output]
        [f.write(x+'\n') for x in blank]
        f.close()
```

Nothing at all changes in the txt file, but the file has string 'VarList' in one of the lines. So, why isn't it working?

Then:

```
import re

def trim(test_string, removal_string):
    return re.sub(r'^(.*?)('+ removal_string + ')(.*)$', r'\1' + r'\2', test_string)

def cleanFile(file_path, removal_string):
    with open(file_path) as master_text:
        return trim(master_text, removal_string)

cleanFile(r'C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Documents\LAB\lean\sample_01.02_R00.txt', 'VarList')
```

and I get this error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [2], in <cell line: 16>()
     13     with open(file_path) as master_text:
     14         return trim(master_text, removal_string)
---> 16 cleanFile(r'C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Documents\LAB\lean\sample_01.02_R00.txt', 'VarList')

Input In [2], in cleanFile(file_path, removal_string)
     12 def cleanFile(file_path, removal_string):
     13     with open(file_path) as master_text:
---> 14         return trim(master_text, removal_string)

Input In [2], in trim(test_string, removal_string)
      9 def trim(test_string, removal_string):
---> 10     return re.sub(r'^(.*?)('+ removal_string + ')(.*)$', r'\1' + r'\2', test_string)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py:210, in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    203 def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
    204     """Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
    205     non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
    206     replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
    207     if a string, backslash escapes in it are processed.  If it is
    208     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    209     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 210     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Finally, I have tried:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Documents\LAB\lean\sample_01.02_R00.txt', 'r') as importFile, open(r'C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Documents\LAB\lean\sample_01.02_R00_temp.txt', 'w') as exportFile:
    head, sep, tail = importFile.partition('VarList')
    exportFile = head

importFile.close()
exportFile.close()
```

Error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [2], in <cell line: 3>()
> 1 # Solution 3
> 3 with open(r'C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Documents\LAB\lean\sample_01.02_R00.txt', 'r') as importFile,
> open(r'C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Documents\LAB\lean\sample_01.02_R00_temp.txt', 'w') as
> exportFile:
> ----> 4     head, sep, tail = importFile.partition('VarList')
> 5     exportFile = head
> 7 importFile.close()
>
> AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute
> 'partition'

Does anyone have a clue about what is going on in here?

Comment: You are appending the `Varlist` line to your output.  Change the order of your `append` and `if..break` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this task could be made easier by using Python's [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) as it has some useful methods for reading and writing text files.

pathlib also has `glob` functionality that allows the addition of “**” to mean “this directory and all subdirectories, recursively”.

For truncating the file, I have chosen to use Python's list comprehension to find the line that starts with the required string and then slice the list of lines at that point.

For example:

```py
from pathlib import Path


def trim_file(filename: Path, end_before: str) -> None:
    content = filename.read_text().splitlines()
    location = [content.index(line)
                for line in content if end_before in line]
    if location:
        filename.write_text("\n".join(content[:location[0]]))


def uppercase_file(filename: Path):
    """extra method to answer a question in the comments below"""
    content = []
    for line in filename.read_text().splitlines():
        content.append(line.upper())
    filename.write_text("\n".join(content))


def main():
    search_directory = Path.home().joinpath('Documents', 'LAB')
    for txt_file in search_directory.glob("**/*.txt"):
        trim_file(txt_file, 'VarList')
        # Example of adding second function to work on same file
        uppercase_file(txt_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you @ukBaz, I am going to study python's pathlib and will be back to post something.

Comment: Ok, I've implemented your solution but unfortunately the line with 'VarList' and all the following content remain there. I added 'lean' to the joinpath, '.joinpath('Documents', 'LAB', 'lean'), and 2 spaces that exist before the target string, ...(search_directory, '  
 VarList') but again nothing has changed in the file. Observe that line must HAVE 'VarList', but it does not necessarily START with 'VarList' - as a matter of fact there are two spaces before that string.

Comment: I've updated the example to find the word anywhere in the line. I suspect your search_directory line  needs to be `search_directory = Path.home().joinpath('OneDrive', 'Documents', 'LAB', 'lean')`. Other than that, what I've provided should be a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the file you provided in your question. If it doesn't work then please edit your question to add more information so I can reproduce what you have.

Comment: Now the code is running like a clock! Thank you @ukBaz.

Comment: Hi @ukBaz, your code can be used on multiple files and that is what I need. However, my script also implements other operations and because of that it can only process a file at a time. As a matter of fact, I realized I have struggled with implementing my coding on multiple files and how important it is to work with modules like 'pathlib'. Would you (or anyone) please suggest a good online course or any other sources that I could use to master handling and implementing code on many files (for example, a course on 'pathlib' or 'os')?

Comment: Probably too big a question for the comment section of SO. However, as a general comment, it is maybe not more information on specific libraries you need information on but more information on "software design principles". For example if you write your core function was to only work with a single file and then have a separate function to be concerned with calling that function on each file. This will make code easier to extend, reuse, and test. Search for terms like "software design principles", "python design patterns", and "making python code testable" should turn up useful ideas for you.

Comment: Thank you @ukBaz, I am now using your latest contribution, as I think it generalizes better.

Answer (score 1):

You're appending to the output before you check for "VarList". The correct way would be:

```
with open(file, 'r') as inF:
    for line in inF:      
        if 'VarList' in line:
            break
        output.append(line)
```

Comment: It hasn't changed the output file. All lines after 'VarList' are still there :(

Comment: Thanks Jakob. I see that the problem is in this line: 'for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\nigel\OneDrive\Documents\LAB\lean\.txt"): for file in files:' When I implement Jakob's solution on a single file, it works pretty well, but it wont work with the os.walk()